# OpenCart 2.3 - Controller default and custom template

Tags: opencart, opencart2.3

I am following the book [OpenCart Theme and Module development](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/opencart-theming)

In chapter 3 it states:

For example, you can refer to catalog/controller/account/account.php. You
will find the following code in it:

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/account/account.tpl')) {
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/account/account.tpl';
} else {
    $this->template = 'default/template/account/account.tpl';
}
```

However, it is not possible to find this code excerpt while checking catalog/controller/account/account.php.

Where is this check in OpenCart 2.3?

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Can you explain further.

Comment: Understand where is that code in OpenCart 2.3 that checks if file is present or not. According to the book it shall be there so I guess it has been moved from previous OpenCart 2.x versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading view in OpeCart 2.3:

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('account/account', $data));
```

You may want to ckeck these files:

```
system\library\response.php
system\engine\loader.php
system\library\template.php
```